# How to check if a group of record are equal?

Tags: php, mysql

Take this table:

```
id | field1 | foreign
 1    abc       12
 2    def       12
 3    abc       13
 4    def       13
```

I select this record like this:

```
"SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE foreign = 12"
```

AND

```
"SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE foreign = 13"
```

Now considering my table this select returns exactly the same records value.
How can I tell that given 2 arbitrary SELECT they retunrs the same value in SQL?

PS. Considering you were voting to close this question I have reformulated it. thanks
PS2. I have other field other than field1
PS3. I know I can do it via PHP, but is there a way pure-SQL?

Comment: What exactly you want? to check duplicate records in a group or compare 2 groups?

Comment: compare 2 groups of record (coming of course from the same table) to see if there are any differecnes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use md5sum to confirm whether 2 result sets are equal or not, this is very useful when comparing two large result sets. Just use the following command within mysql console:

pager md5sum -

This will set the MySQL pager to display the MD5Sum after every query that is run.

If you are using PHP to run each query then you could create the same effect using this method:

```
// This method will return MD5 of a result set. Compared results will return the same     MD5Sum if they have the same results, and are ordered in the same way. 
function query_md5($sql) {
 $rs = mysql_query($sql);
 $num = mysql_num_fields($rs);
 $str = "";
 while ($obj = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
  $i = 0;
  while ($i < $num) {
   // no need for spaces or formatting
   $str .= $obj[$i++];
  }
 }
 return md5($str);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will confirm if two result sets are equal or not. If the hash of both queries is the same, then results from both queries are same. This gives you a very effective comparison. From how you have phrased the question this should be a suitable solution.